# Does session timeout also kill datasource connection?

Tags: java, servlets, datasource, web.xml

I have a java servlet application with the session timeout set to 35 minutes in web.xml. However sometimes the application fails with the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00028: your session has been killed
```

Also in web.xml, the datasource is set up as follows:

```
<resource-ref>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/RemittancePDFMappedDS</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

The DBAs have confirmed that they are not killing anything. This is a multithreaded application, however no connections are being programmatically killed. My question is: when the application times out after 35 minutes, does this also invalidate the datasource? To resolve this, we usually just restart and it works correctly for a while until the same error occurs again.

Comment: HTTP session is not same as DB session. Your problem is caused elsewhere (perhaps too high DB session timeout in client side?)

Answer (score 0):

It should not be related. The SQL exception is caused for another reason that it is not possible to determine with the info provided.

But, you can manage that problem using features of `jndi-resources`. Check if you have configured your data source using `validationQuery` and `testOnBorrow` attributes.

This way, your connection pool can check if a connection has been closed, and reopen it. Due to you are using Oracle DB you can use this generic validation query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

This won't solve the problem that is causing database session kill, but it would reconnect as needed.